# subadditivity of complex numbers on the real line

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I am trying to prove that an integral given by

\begin{equation}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} |f|^2 dx 
\end{equation}
diverges where $f$ is complex.

I can show easily that
\begin{equation}
|\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f^2 dx|
\end{equation}
diverges.

I want to know if
\begin{equation}
|\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f^2 dx|\leq  \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} |f|^2 dx 
\end{equation}
on the real line.

I looked at the wikipedia page on the absolute value, and it just said that it held for a measurable subset $E$. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) Unfortunately, I am a big lost regarding what a measurable subset is.

Comment: Have you tried squaring the inequality so it becomes a comparison of two double integrals?

Comment: We have $|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g| \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g|$ for any measurable function $g$ for which the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g^+ - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g^-$ is defined .